# System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed

Tags: c#, .net, injeção-de-dependência

Olá estou construindo uma API Rest. Estou tentando fazer uma conexão da interface IFileBusiness para FileBusiness no arquivo Starup.cs do .net5, mas estou pegando o seguinte erro:

> An error occurred while starting the application.
> AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: RestWithASPNETUdemy.Business.IFileBusiness Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: RestWithASPNETUdemy.Business.Implementations.FileBusiness': Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'RestWithASPNETUdemy.Business.Implementations.FileBusiness'.)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable serviceDescriptors, IServiceProviderEngine engine, ServiceProviderOptions options)

Meu trecho de código do arquivo startup.cs:

```
        services.AddScoped<IFileBusiness, FileBusiness>();
        services.AddScoped<IPersonBusiness, PersonBusinessImplementation>();
        services.AddScoped<IBookBusiness, BookBusinessImplementation>();
        services.AddScoped<ILoginBusiness, LoginBusinessImplementation>();

        services.AddTransient<ITokenService, TokenService>();

        services.AddScoped<IUsersRepository, UsersRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IPersonRepository, PersonRepository>();
        //services.AddScoped<IPersonRepository, PersonRepository>();

        services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>)); ;
```

O código do arquivo FileBusiness e IFileBusiness

```
insira o código aqui
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using RestWithASPNETUdemy.Data.VO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RestWithASPNETUdemy.Business.Implementations
{
public class FileBusiness : IFileBusiness
{
    private readonly string _basePath;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _context;

    public FileBusiness(string basePath, IHttpContextAccessor context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _basePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\UploadDir\\";
    }

    public byte[] GetFile(string filename)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
    public async Task<FileDetailVO> SaveFileToDisk(IFormFile file)
    {
        FileDetailVO fileDetail= new FileDetailVO();

        var fileType = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
        var baseUrl = _context.HttpContext.Request.Host; // Pega endereço da applicação ex ta no localhost:4000,
                                                         // ta no servidor da azure também vai pegar tbm.

        if (fileType.ToLower() == ".pdf" || fileType.ToLower() == ".jpg" ||
            fileType.ToLower() == ".png" || fileType.ToLower() == ".jpeg")
        {
            var docName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
            {
                var destination = Path.Combine(_basePath, "", docName);
                fileDetail.DocumentName = docName;
                fileDetail.DocType = fileType;
                fileDetail.DocUrl = Path.Combine(baseUrl + "/api/file/v1/" + fileDetail.DocumentName); // montando o link para
                                                                                                       // download do arquivo

                using var stream = new FileStream(destination, FileMode.Create);
                await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
        }
        return fileDetail;
    }

    public Task<List<FileDetailVO>> SaveFilesToDisk(IList<IFormFile> file)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

}

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using RestWithASPNETUdemy.Data.VO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RestWithASPNETUdemy.Business
{
     public interface IFileBusiness
    {
        public byte[] GetFile(string filename);
        public Task<FileDetailVO> SaveFileToDisk(IFormFile file);
        public Task<List<FileDetailVO>> SaveFilesToDisk(IList<IFormFile> file);

   }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na sua classe `FileBusiness` você tem um parâmetro no construtor que não pode ser entendido pela injeção de dependência.

O parâmetro `string basePath` pode ser qualquer coisa e por isso, a injeção de dependência não conseguir identificar com qual valor ela deveria atribuir a este parâmetro para ativar sua classe.

Você pode resolver isso indicando os parâmetros necessários para ativação da sua classe de forma explicita.

Exemplo:

```
services.AddScoped<IFileBusiness>(s => new FileBusiness("VALOR", s.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>()));
```

Outra forma de resolver isso é receber uma interface ou classe que resolva o `basePath`.
Exemplo:

```
// Registro do serviço
services.AddScoped<IBasePathResolver , BasePathResolver >();

// Recebendo ele por parâmetro.
public FileBusiness(IBasePathResolver basePathResolver, IHttpContextAccessor context)
{
    _context = context;
    _basePath = basePathResolver.Resolve();
}
```

Mas no fim, resumindo, o parâmetro `basePath` não está sendo usado pelo seu construtor... então é só remover ele que irá funcionar.